# How set default address for customers via SQL

Tags: customer, mysql

How can I **configure the default address in magento via SQL**.

I have over *7000 users*, however some of them are not defined.

Each client has ~2 registered address, I would like that the two addresses were marked one as the default billing and another shipping.

Via **SQL** there is some command?

The default could be the first one found, or the first encountered.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cjtn.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "default address"? Can you give an example? Assigning a fixed street address to each customer does not sound useful to me.

Comment: Each client has ~2 registered address, I would like that the two addresses were marked one as the default billing and another shipping. Like the image http://i.imgur.com/aV6onTe.jpg

Comment: You can set default billing and default shipping to an existing customer address via SQL. But by which logic would you determine which of them is the billing address and which the shipping address?

Comment: It could be the first one found, or the first encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Disclaimer: Please make a backup of your database and/or test on a copy before trying out the query!***

To set the first found customer address as default shipping address, use

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity_int (entity_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, value)
  SELECT
    e.entity_id,
    1,
    (SELECT
      attribute_id
    FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code = 'default_shipping'),
    address.entity_id
  FROM customer_entity e
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int v
    ON v.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND v.attribute_id = (SELECT
      attribute_id
    FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code = 'default_shipping')
  INNER JOIN customer_address_entity address
    ON address.parent_id = e.entity_id
  WHERE value_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY e.entity_id
```

Then repeat with `'default_shipping'` replaced by `'default_billing'` in both places.

This will probably set the same address as default for both but since it is an arbitrary choice anyway I did not go the extra mile to write a second query that compares the address against the assigned shipping address.

*Updated with tested query*

Comment: Did not work. )):
0 row (s) inserted. (A query took 0.0356 seconds.)

Comment: Please try to change the last inner join to a left join. If that doesn't work I'll have to test..

Comment: Now return: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`customer_entity_int`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CSTR_ENTT_INT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`)

Comment: fschmengler, please, could you check your code?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: )): what's happen? The same error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`customer_entity_int`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CSTR_ENTT_INT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I actually only tested the SELECT, forgot about adding entity_type_id to the columns

Comment: Now, this one actually works :)

Comment: woooow! the code really works. Thx man. Amazing.

Comment: a question, you set "value_id IS NULL" in the code. It applies only to users who have non-standard address defined, or for all records?

Comment: This is to select all users that do *not* have a default shipping address.

Comment: This works great for me, Fabian. People need to upvote this more as it saves me a buttload of time.